# How to time a jQuery game with php

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a jQuery game where the player has to complete a task in the quickest time possible.
I display a timer so the user knows how long they are taking to complete the task.

I've been reading up on cheating/hacking and it seems the only way to prevent it is to keep the important logic server side. My server side language of choice is php.
As the important logic for my game is the time taken, I can set a timer when the game starts, and stop the timer with an ajax call when the game ends.

I'm just wondering what to do if there is a lag between the ajax call being made and the server receiving the call.
Say the user completes the task in 12 seconds but there is a 1 second lag for the ajax caqll to be recieved.
The value written to the highscore table will be 13 seconds which will make for an unhappy player!

Is the server side timer/ajax call the way to go here? Am I worrying too much about a lag? Is there a better way to go about timing a game?

This is my first ever game so I'm unsure about the best way to stop cheating!

Comment: I think you cannot help it because if you send a timestamp through AJAX call and validate that, then this leaves a big chance for the user to cheat

Comment: At the end, you can't prevent cheating. If you worry about the lag, you should take the time client-side, because there the game actually runs.

Comment: So are we saying it is impossible to time the game both accurately AND prevent cheating? To time the game server side, I need some kind of trigger from the browser to tell the php script the game has ended. This gives me the lag problem. If I time the game client side, the player can cheat :(

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop cheating this way, because no matter how much you try, the Javascript on your page is editable by anyone who hits F12.

Having the timer on the server would make it inaccurate, because the delay from your script to the server will be different for everyone. I would just suggest making the game first.